# How to handle null value in the request in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a rest API where I need to send page num as query parameter.
When I send null, it gives me a bad request.
Below is the rest API code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)

@ResponseBody
public String sample(
        @RequestParam(value = "page-number", required = false, defaultValue = "1")  final Integer pageNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "page-size", required = false, defaultValue = "50")  final Integer pageSize) {

    return "hello";
}
```

I am hitting the API with the following URL http://localhost:8000/sample?pageNumber=null

I am getting the below exception

```
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"null\"",
```

How do I handle null case?

Comment: Rather than attempting to pass `null`, just remove the parameter from the URL .

Comment: The Exception is clearly saying what the problem is.

Comment: why do you want to send null?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/sample should be your URL..

Comment: I have understood the exception,that it is because of null being considered as string but how do I handle it,if in case it is passed? @MehrajMalik

Comment: You can use `interceptors` to intercept incoming `requests` and check, modify as you need before calling the specific **Controller method**

Comment: cant we set to default value if null is passed ? @coder-croc

Comment: @yacky `null` is not a HTTP standard though. If you don't want to pass a page number, and you want to use the default, you should remove the parameter as mentioned by @Berger and @coder-croc, or you should leave the parameter blank, eg `http://localhost:8000/sample?pageNumber`. Anything else you'll have to program manually. The question is, why would you send `null` though.

Answer (score 2):

While hitting any HTTP request, if you don't want to send any value of  any request parameter, then please don't include that specific parameter in URL instead of sending null value to that parameter.

For e.g.
If you don't want to send any value in pageNumber request parameter, then please don't include pageNumber in request parameter.
So your request URL will be: `http://localhost:8000/sample`

If you will hit URL something like `http://localhost:8000/sample?pageNumber=null`, then it will map "null" string literal to pageNumber request param, and you will get following exception:

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"null\"",

because you are expecting an Integer value that should be mapped with pageNumber request parameter not a string literal.

Comment: And How to handle with wrong parameter name? can it be catch with a predefined exceptions and handled accordingly?